# Can a web api post method contains more than one parameter?

Tags: post, parameters, asp.net-web-api

I have this method in a controller in a web api

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(string name, string password){
        //dothings
    }
}
```

but if I try a ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:19860/Api/User/Login",
    data: { name: "name", password: "12345" },
    success: succ,
    error: err
});
```

It gives me the error:

Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:19860/Api/User/Login'."
MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request."

but, if i remove the parameters it works!

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(){
        string name=  HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["name"];
        string password= HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["password"];
        // name and password have the value that i passed in the ajax call!!
    }
}
```

why it is like this?

For reasons unrelated to this question, I can't change the web api, so I have to mantain the:

public HttpResponseMessage Login(string name, string password)

format.

Can I mantain this format and be able to make the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not post multiple parameter to Web-API methods as mentioned in [this blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods)

There is few alternative to this as follow.

**1**. Try to pass it on queryString.

Change your ajax function call like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:19860/Api/User/Login?name=name&pass=pass",
    data: { name: "name", password: "12345" },
    success: succ,
    error: err
});
```

you will get name = name and password = pass in your api controller.

**2**. Create your own binder as implemented in [this blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API).

**3**. Wrap all the Web-API method parameter in one object or type (**recommended**).

From the above you can use 1st and 2nd approach as you mentioned in your question you can not change your api method signature.

Comment: @AlbertCortada Welcome Just **Note**: passing credential over url is not good practise so I would suggest to go with third option if possible for you.

Comment: Right now it's not possible to me, but I will take this into consideration in upcoming code reviews